# how to pull the updated PR of github

Tags: git, github

I have pulled the PR from github, now someone else updated the PR. Then how can I update the PR in my local ? The following command doesn't work for me.

```
git pull upstream pr/2329
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref pr/2329
```

I can see pr/2329 in git branch -r command, and also I can see upstream in git remote -v

Comment: Make sure your branch name is correct. Do you see `pr/2329` in `git branch -r` command?

Comment: Try using `git remote -v` ... make sure that `upstream` appears and that it points to the right GitHub.

Comment: I can see pr/2329 in git branch -r command, and also I can see upstream in git remote -v

Comment: Do you have pr/2329 in upstream? May it be that you only have it in origin? As far as I know pull requests are moved to origin and for most of the branches I create they do not exist in upstream since they are merged to the master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout pr/2329
git pull upstream pull/2329/head
```

`pr/2329` is your local branch that you've created for that Pull Request. Switch to it and update from pull request. Pull requests at Github are just branches in `pull/` namespace.